# Python tuples, what does , in the end mean

Tags: python

```
(0,)==(0)
False
```

What does , in (0,) means and when it is usefull to have that kind of tuple instead of the regular tuple like (0)?

I thought it might mean that item in index 1 is None but thats not the case :

```
(0,)[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Also, if i want (0,1,) to become (0,1) how do i manipulate it?

**EDIT:**

Maybe i over simplified the example used for my problem, this is my original problem :

```
(('Suggest', 1.0), 65)==((('Suggest', 1.0),), 65)
False
```

So i guess python doesnt interpert ('Suggest', 1.0) as mathematical expression does it?

Comment: `(0)` is not a tuple.

Comment: @StephenRauch why? and what is it?

Comment: Do the dupes help?

Comment: @StephenRauch A little, so does that mean ('Suggest', 1.0) is not a tuple? then what is it?

Comment: `('Suggest', 1.0)` is a two element tuple. `(('Suggest', 1.0), )` is a one element tuple containing a two element tuple.

Comment: @StephenRauch I see it now, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(0)` wouldn't be interpreted by Python as a tuple, but instead as a numeric expression (like `(1+2)` except without any math operation). The trailing comma is used to tell Python that it is explicitly a 1-element tuple.

```
>>> type((0))
<type 'int'>
>>> type((0,))
<type 'tuple'>
```

`(0)` evaluates to a number:

```
>>> (0) == 0
True
```

`(0,)` evaluates to a tuple, which is not a number...

> > > (0,) == 0
> > >           False

...but is a tuple.

```
>>> (0,) == tuple([0])
True
```

This isn't specific to numbers, either - `(expression)` will always be equivalent to `expression`, while `(expression,)` will always be a single-element tuple with the first (and only) item in the tuple being the result of `expression`.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: @OfekRon `("foo")` is still different from `("foo",)` - without the `,` the parentheses get ignored in favor of the expression inside them. With the `,` it defines a tuple.